# Greyhound rash after pet boarding

Tags: dogs

We picked up our 3-year-old greyhound after she was boarded for a week at the local animal hospital. When we got home we discovered that she had the rash in the photo below.

We took her back to the vet where she was boarded, and they don't know what it is. They're saying that it's bruising and did blood work. The blood work numbers look absolutely perfect for a greyhound, but they're concerned about her low white count and high platelet count, low for most dogs, but perfect for greyhounds.

The second photo is from the next day. They drew circles around the discoloration to gauge any change. The photos show that it got closer to purple in the day that passed.

I've read that rashes happen for various reasons, and the vet is calling it a bruise.

Is this something to be concerned with?

[image: First image]

[image: Second image]

Comment: yes this is something to be conserned of those bruises did not come there by them selves,if you had these bruises on half your belly you had been conserned too. in my opinion.

Comment: Without the blood works I'd say it looks similar to the rash my dog had after having her belly shaved at the vet. The skin was irritated badly and it took us more than a week to get rid of it. On your photos it does look like it's on parts of the belly/chest that dogs lay on so skin irritation is a possibility imo. If it is bruises like the vet says and related to the results of the blood works it probably requires more check ups.

Comment: can you post the bloodwork results?

Comment: @RebeccaRVT Thanks for asking... I will get those numbers a bit later today.